# Python - Keeping some HTML tags with lxml Xpath feature

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I am writing some HTML parsers using LXML Xpath feature. It seems to be working fine, but I have one main problem.

When parsing all the HTML `<p>` tags, there are words that use the tags `<b>`, `<i>` and etc. I need to keep those tags.

When parsing the HTML, for example;

```
<div class="ArticleDetail">
    <p>Hello world, this is a <b>simple</b> test, which contains words in <i>italic</i> and others.
    I have a <strong>strong</strong> tag here. I guess this is a silly test.
    <br/>
    Ops, line breaks.
    <br/></p>
```

If I run this Python code;

```
x = lxml.html.fromstring("...html text...").xpath("//div[@class='ArticleDetail']/p")
for stuff in x:
    print stuff.text_content()
```

This seems to work fine, but it removes all the other tags instead of p only.

Output:

```
Hello world, this is a simple test, which contains words in italic and others.
I have a strong tag here. I guess this is a silly test.
Ops, line breaks.
```

As you can see it removed all the `<b>`, `<i>` and `<strong>` tags. Is there anyway you can keep them?

Comment: Thanks for editing, forgot to add those tags to code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently retrieving only the text content, not the HTML content (which would include tags).

You want to retrieve all child nodes of your XPath match instead:

```
from lxml import etree

x = lxml.html.fromstring("...html text...").xpath("//div[@class='ArticleDetail']/p")
for elem in x:
    for child in elem.iterdescendants():
        print etree.tostring(child)
```

Comment: Interesting. I ran the code it works fine, except I see that </br> is being replaced by a \n. Is this normal? if so why, and is there a way I can catch the <\br>? Thanks.

Comment: @BenMezger: Your example has invalid `<br/>` tags (the slash is in the wrong place). They are thus dropped by the parser, the newlines were already there, not the result of the faulty tags.